# Installation Instructions for CAFFE (CPU Version) for Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: debian, installation, debian-stretch, caffe

I had difficulty installing Caffe (CPU Version) from source on Debian 9 Stretch. (Encountered link errors when running `make all`, associated with blas/liblapack)

In the answer below I have listed the terminal commands which I ran in order to install Caffe. I tested this in a new Virtualbox installation of Debian 9, from the DVD image (DVD1.iso)

Address: https://saimei.ftp.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-9.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

Also available at: https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable, click the link for "DVD"/amd64.

It is (probably?) important to specify the exact version of Debian that I used during this installation process. Other versions of the install (eg; from CD) *should* work, but you might need to install other packages which I did not have to install. The date is 2017-12-13.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal commands: Note these worked inside a fresh install inside a virtual machine. They did NOT work on an existing installation of the same operating system, which means that either

- I forgot which version of the debian distribution I installed on my machine. (It is Stretch, but might have been the CD install not the DVD one.)
- Or, I installed some other stuff in the mean time which changed my OS in such a way that the installation of Caffe fails. I have no clue why this happens.

## Run the following terminal commands to install dependencies

```
# Update system
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
# Install general development tools
sudo apt install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config git
# Install blas
sudo apt install -y libopenblas-*
# Install boost
sudo apt install -y libboost-all-dev
# Install open CV
sudo apt install -y libopencv-dev
# Install protobuf
sudo apt install -y protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev
# Install other dependencies
sudo apt install -y libgflags-dev libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev liblmdb-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libgoogle-glog-dev
# Install python dependencies
python python-pip python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python3 python3-pip python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-dev
```

## Clone caffe

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
cd caffe
```

## Copy Makefile.config.example and change settings prior to build

```
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
vim Makefile.config
```

Here is the diff output after I edited it for CPU only build

```
8c8
< # CPU_ONLY := 1
---
> CPU_ONLY := 1
51c51
< BLAS := atlas
---
> BLAS := open
95c95
< INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
---
> INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
```

In summary, I enabled CPU_ONLY build mode, change the BLAS to OpenBLAS and added an include directory; `/usr/include/hdf5/serial`. Without this extra directory the build fails with error "could not find hdf5.h".

*Note:* You may also need to uncomment the line `OPENCV_VERSION := 3` if you are using OpenCV version 3.

## Install extra python packages

```
cd python
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip install $req; done
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip3 install $req; done
```

Notice that I do everything for both python and python3. There is a method to switch between which version of python caffe uses when building the python packages, but I don't yet know how to do this, so I just install both and hope for the best.

## Make symbolic links for hdf5 libs

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1 libhdf5.so
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0 libhdf5_hl.so
```

## Build

```
cd ~/caffe
make all
make test
make runtest
make pycaffe
make distribute
// TODO: move make distribute output to correct place
// figure out what to do with other files in distribute directory
```

## Move distribute files to correct location

```
cd distribute
sudo cp -r ./bin/* /bin/
sudo cp -r ./include/* /usr/include/
sudo cp -r ./lib/* /usr/lib
```

I have no idea what to do with the `proto` and `python` directories.

Comment: how does this have no upvotes

Comment: Agreed! Very useful! Use `find /usr -iname "*hdf5.h*"` to find the exact pathing! Also! For whoever that needs it, on my embedded system, for the symlinks, it's in `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`